# How to split an 8 bit BCD number into two separate 4 bit BCD numbers using logic gates or VHDL?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I think this might actually be quite simple but I can't find info on it anywhere and I can't think how I would do it. I want to split an 8 bit BCD into two 4 bit BCDs so for example if I get an input of:

01011100 I want two separate outputs of 0101 and 1100.

Similarly how could I then split the 0101 into 4 outputs of 0, 1, 0, 1 and the same for the 1100 into 1, 1, 0, 0?

Comment: It's just a lane change. I don't see the complexity here. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This takes no hardware whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VHDL, you can directly slice the array. Let's assume `allparts` is the 8 bit BCD array you want to slice, and `first_part` and `second_part` are the 4 bit BCD signals you need.

`allparts`, `first_parts` and `second_parts` is of type `std_logic_vector`.

```
firstpart <= allparts(7 downto 4);
secondpart <= allparts(3 downto 0);
```

...or if `firstpart` and `secondpart` are simply alternate ways to refer to part of the `allparts` signal, you may want to use an `alias`:

```
alias firstpart is allparts(7 downto 4);
alias secondpart is allparts(3 downto 0);
```

Credits: Charles Steinkuehler
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376420/12311164

Comment: Is there a logic gate way as well?

Comment: @Matt you don't need a logic gate here since you don't have a **function** for the logic gate to perform. You can either directly connect 4 bits as a separate signal or use a buffer.